# python remove brackets if followed by words

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

I am trying to remove brackets `[]` if there are words in them. For example in the sentence below, I am trying to remove the `[]` around `result`. I tried `\[[A-Za-z]` which can pick up the open bracket `[`, but I couldn't figure out how to detect the close bracket `]` and how to delete them. Could someone please help? Many thanks.

```
This should be in the [result].
```

Comment: You need to escape the `]` with `\]`

Comment: `r = re.sub(r"\[([^]]+)\]", r"\1"", s)` - https://trinket.io/python3/9f0a3ca34d

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: @PedroLobito Thanks! this is what I'm looking for. Could you explain a bit more about your answer like `\1` and the use of ^ here? I thought ^ was for negate. If you move this to an answer I could accept it.

Comment: @user3735871 https://regex101.com/r/MLHq1K/1 - Check the regex explanation on the right side.